# Kindle Keyboard shortcut for returning to last "page"

Tags: kindle

I have a Kindle Keyboard, and sometimes, while reading a book, if I press on the left/right key, it will throw me off to the previous/next chapter's first page.
(the nearby up/down keys invoke the dictionary, so this does happen...)

Does anyone know of any shortcut that can be used to go back to my original place? Even after the throw-off, there's a little cursor on the "progress bar" at the bottom that shows where I've previously been, so I suspect such shortcut exists.

Answer (score 2):

The [back button](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=200375790) gives you back to your original place.